# epublib sometimes cannot read a file

Tags: java, android, epublib

Hello!

I need to extract resources from a `epub-file`, and I use for this `ebublib`. It works very well with a lot of files, but sometimes I get `NullPointerException.`

There is my code:

```java
InputStream bookInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(bookFile));

Book book = new EpubReader().readEpub(bookInputStream);
Collection<Resource> clrst = book.getResources().getAll();
int all = clrst.size();
int curr = 0;
for (Resource rs : clrst) {
    Log.d(TAG, ++curr + "/" + all + " | " + rs.getSize());
    builder.setProgress(all, curr, false);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

    File oppath1 = new File(directory + File.separator + rs.getHref());
    oppath1.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    oppath1.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(oppath1);
    fos1.write(rs.getData());
    fos1.close();
}
```

And there is stacktrace:

```java
10-12 11:23:29.668  24731-25088/ru.intuit.nou I/AndroidLoggerFactory﹕ Logger name 'nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubProcessorSupport' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'n*.s*.e*.e*.EpubProces*' instead. 10-12 11:23:29.684  24731-25088/ru.intuit.nou I/AndroidLoggerFactory﹕ Logger name 'nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.PackageDocumentReader' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'n*.s*.e*.e*.PackageDoc*' instead. 10-12 11:23:29.692  24731-25088/ru.intuit.nou E/n*.s*.e*.e*.EpubReader﹕ null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.PackageDocumentReader.read(PackageDocumentReader.java:51)
            at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.processPackageResource(EpubReader.java:119)
            at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readEpub(EpubReader.java:97)
            at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readEpub(EpubReader.java:53)
            at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.readEpub(EpubReader.java:37)
            at ru.intuit.nou.fragments.CourseInfoFragment$DownloadTask.downloadResources(CourseInfoFragment.java:1269)
            at ru.intuit.nou.fragments.CourseInfoFragment$DownloadTask.doInBackground(CourseInfoFragment.java:1140)
            at ru.intuit.nou.fragments.CourseInfoFragment$DownloadTask.doInBackground(CourseInfoFragment.java:1047)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 10-12 11:23:29.692  24731-25088/ru.intuit.nou I/AndroidLoggerFactory﹕ Logger name 'nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.NCXDocument' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'n*.s*.e*.e*.NCXDocument' instead. 10-12 11:23:29.692  24731-25088/ru.intuit.nou E/n*.s*.e*.e*.NCXDocument﹕ Book does not contain a table of contents file
```

I have no idea why it does not work with some epub-files, and I will be glad with any help. Thanks in advance!